# limit of game center achievements you can have

Tags: ios, game-center

Just a quick little question is there a limit to the amount of achievements you can have?
And how much should i use for my game? Just a small game btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There are limits to how many achievements you can create in your game
>   and how many points you can reward to the player:
>
> - Each game can have up to 100 achievements.
> - Each game can award up to 1000 points.
> - No individual achievement can award more than 100 points.

See also the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html)

Comment: How totally arbitrary!